# How to get SHA256 code for object in dart?

Tags: serialization, hash, dart, flutter, sha

I need to get sha256 code (hex string) for Object. I can get this for String - the result will be equal (verified on some online sites); But I dont know how to get sha256 for dart Object, not for string. In java this possible to do when you make byte[] from Object, dart doesn't support object serialization. so If somebody knows how can i handle with this, please?

Comment: Each Dart object [already has a `hashCode`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html) property, although it won't be SHA-256, and it's possible that there will be collisions.  Additionally, if you create the "same" object across different runs of your application (i.e., you took the same steps to create the object), you could end up with different `hashCode` values because they aren't the same object in memory.  This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Reason that I need not to get hash. I need to get sha256 for object, in conclusion, this required to verify if object was modified / changed. This similar like for c# or java: transform object (class, string, etc.) into byte array and then get sha256 from it. But I am not sure that dart can transform dart object (Object  - class) into byte array. I can easy to get sha256 for String, and this will be identical for c# and java, but how to get for object?

Comment: You can't know if an arbitrary object has been modified.  What does the definition of "modified" mean?  Suppose `Foo` contains a `final Bar` member, and something within `Bar` changed.  Is that a modification of the `Foo` object?  What if the `final Bar` member is private and not externally visible from `Foo`?  Is that still a modification?  Only *you* can define what these things mean.  Only *you* can specify how you want various objects to be serialized.

Comment: Anyway, how can I get Sha256 from Dart object, not string, Object required? In java this possible to transform object into byte array and then get sha 256. how to do this in Dart?

Comment: *You* have to define how you want objects to be serialized into bytes.  Only then can you generate a sha-256 hash of those bytes.

Comment: See https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/serialization.